# FileNotFoundException in a testing a Maven module

Tags: spring, testing, maven-2

I'm working on a recently mavenized legacy project with following multi-modular structure:

Parent:

- Web
- Service
- Dao

("Service" module is dependent on "Dao" module)

**Problem**: some tests of Service classes call DAO code that creates beans using Spring's ClassPathXmlApplicationContext (this part is not really DAOs but caching related). Since, ClassPathXmlApplicationContext uses spring config xml of the DAO module - the Service tests fail throwing FileNotFoundException. I think this is because tests run in Service module and the spring config xml being referred lies in Dao module.

Please advise on how can I resolve the above issue in tests referring to code/resources of other modules?

Comment: could you share your context loading statement (that loads the spring config file) ?

Comment: this is how context is loaded: CONTEXT = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a copy of the Spring configuration under src/test/resources in the Service module. Quite often you want a different configuration for testing anyway, but also it means your tests are less dependent on configuration changes in another module.